# Microsoft ReportViewer ThreadAbortException on Export cancel

Tags: c#, export, reportviewer, thread-abort

I have a windows form program with microsoft report viewer in form. When i generate report and select `Export to Excel` (Little icon with floppy disk and green arrow) it starts exporting. But if i press `Cancel` while excel file is being generated i get an error: `An Error occured during local report processing. System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.`.
How can i handle this error? If i set report viewer error handler (`this.reportViewer.ReportError += new ReportErrorEventHandler(reportViewer_ReptError);`) i can handle other error, but not this one (breakpoint is never hit).

Comment: Not tested but I would give a look at this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer.reportexport%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I ended up catching export event and exporting files myself. That way i am able to handle all exceptions. Could not find any better solution.